# How to read values from triplet and extract into pair using java stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream

I have a triplet with pattern and string objects. I would like to return the string objects pair if there is a match in pattten.

```
 List<Triplet<Pattern, String, String>> patternMatcher = Arrays.asList(
        Triplet.with(Pattern.compile("check_report_\\d{8}_\\d{8}.csv"), "check-report",
            "CheckReport"),
        Triplet.with(Pattern.compile("\\d{8}-\\d{6}_On_Hand_\\d{4}.csv"),
            "on-hand", "OnHand") 
    );
```

```
String container = patternMatcher
        .stream()
        .map(x -> Pair.with(x.getValue0().matcher(fileName).matches(), x.getValue1()))
        .filter(Pair::getValue0)
        .map(Pair::getValue1)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Unknown file type."));

String directory = patternMatcher
        .stream()
        .map(x -> Pair.with(x.getValue0().matcher(fileName).matches(), x.getValue2()))
        .filter(Pair::getValue0)
        .map(Pair::getValue1)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Unknown file type."));
```

Given fileName -> `check_report_12345678_12345678.csv` , It should return `Pair` of two string objects `check-report` and `CheckReport`.The above `container` will only give me `check-report`.And  `directory` will give me only directory `CheckReport`.. Can someone help me how I can process as `Pair` in single time ? I want that Processed single time and return `Pair`.

Comment: `patternMatcher.stream().filter(x -> x.getValue0().matcher(fileName).matches()).map(x -> Pair.with(x.getValue1(), x.getValue2()))`

Comment: @shmosel It worked.